# Codewars: Reverse or Rotate

Tags: javascript, beginner, programming-challenge

## CodeWars 6 Kyu: Reverse or rotate?

I wrote my Javascript "hello world" on Thursday, so I'm definitely a JS beginner. I do have some experience in Python though, so I'm not a complete novice to programming in general.

### Question

> The input is a string `str` of digits. Cut the string into chunks (a chunk here is a substring of the initial string) of size `sz` (ignore the last chunk if its size is less than `sz`).
>
> If a chunk represents an integer such as the **sum of the cubes of its digits is divisible by 2**, reverse that chunk; otherwise rotate it to the left by one position. Put together these modified chunks and return the result as a string.
>
> If
>
> - `sz` is `<= 0` or if str is empty return `""`
> - `sz` is greater `(>)` than the length of `str` it is impossible to take a chunk of size `sz` hence return `""`.
>
> Examples:

```
revrot("123456987654", 6) --> "234561876549"
revrot("123456987653", 6) --> "234561356789"
revrot("66443875", 4) --> "44668753"
revrot("66443875", 8) --> "64438756"
revrot("664438769", 8) --> "67834466"
revrot("123456779", 8) --> "23456771"
revrot("", 8) --> ""
revrot("123456779", 0) --> "" 
revrot("563000655734469485", 4) --> "0365065073456944"
```

### Solution

```js
function revrot(str, sz) 
{
   ln = str.length;
   if(sz < 1 || !str || sz > ln) return "";

   const test = s => Array.prototype.reduce.call(s, (acc, val) => acc + Number(val) ** 3, 0) % 2 === 0;
   const reverse = s => s.split("").reverse().join("");
   const rotate = s => s.slice(1) + s.slice(0, 1);

   let arr = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < ln; i += sz) arr.push(i+sz <= ln ? str.slice(i, i+sz) : "")
   return arr.map(x => test(x) ? reverse(x) : rotate(x)).join("");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Towards optimization and restructuring*

One of downsides of the initial `revrot` approach is that all nested functions `test`, `reverse` and `rotate` will be redundantly recreated on **each** `revrot` call.
Instead - define them as top-level functions with meaningful names.

Next, the program lacks 2 edge cases:

- when input string contains one single digit and size of required chunk is also `1` (ex. `revrot("3", 1)`). It's worth to catch that case immediately and return the unchanged input string
- when input string contains non-digit character

The intermediate `arr` array with `for` loop and `slice` calls (to get all chunks) is replaced with convenient [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) call on dynamic regex pattern **`` new RegExp(`.{${size}}`, 'g') ``** (matches substrings of specific length/size)

---

The final optimized approach:

```js
const testCubes = s => Array.prototype.reduce.call(s, (acc, val) => acc + Number(val) ** 3, 0) % 2 === 0;
const strReverse = s => [...s].reverse().join("");
const rotateLeft = s => s.slice(1) + s.slice(0, 1);


function revrot(str, size) {
    let len = str.length;
    if (size < 1 || !str || size > len) return "";
    if (len === 1 && size === 1) return str;
    if (/\D/.test(str)) {
        throw Error("Invalid numeric string");
    }
    let pat = new RegExp(`.{${size}}`, 'g');
    return str.match(pat).map(x => 
        testCubes(x) ? strReverse(x) : rotateLeft(x)
    ).join("");
}


console.log(revrot("123456987654", 6));
console.log(revrot("123456987653", 6));
console.log(revrot("66443875", 8));
console.log(revrot("563000655734469485", 4));
console.log(revrot("1", 1));
console.log(revrot("6644-d3875", 8));
```

Comment: Your answer seams to contradict its self. You say don't nest functions yet you declare one inside `map`. Anyways modern JS engines cache functions.. There is no overhead associated with nested functions and it is good practice to encapsulate function within the scope they are used in. -1

Comment: @Blindman67, I don't agree regarding nested functions and don't want wasting my time for such doubtful debates.

Comment: "...doubtful debate.."? This is not a "debate".A performance test is all that is needed to show that moving the functions out makes no difference (a little slower due to  longer scope chain lookups). Additionally I down voted because your function, is a good 25% slower than the OP's, throws a un-required error (feature creep) The error is inconsistent `revrot("aa",1)` throws while `revrot("a",1)` does not and for ill formed args should be a `RangeError`. Also and  not part of down vote but your edge cases missed the most obvious optimization `if (size === 1) { return str }`